# Как правильно сказать "это инженер,а тот учитель",или "этот инженер, а тот учитель"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно сказать "это инженер, а тот учитель", или "этот инженер, а тот учитель"?

Comment: Зависит от контекста.

Comment: Не забывайте о пробелах после запятой. За вопрос - плюс.

Comment: Не  столь  от  контекста,  как  от  ситуации.  Фраза — разговорная.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не надо смешивать: либо это-это, либо этот-этот (тот). Между **этот** и **тот** разница небольшая, в дистанции.